# Has "Save to map" gone from Google Maps Classic?

Tags: google-maps

I am a frequent user of Google Maps, and I have quite a few of "My Maps", where I collect placemarks.

Now I am trying to create a new of these My Maps, and add placemarks to it. After searching for an address or location, there used to be an option to "Save to map". I cannot find it anymore.

http://www.kevinandamanda.com/whatsnew/travel/create-a-custom-travel-map-with-google-maps.html shows instructions for saving to user maps. There is one comment to that post reporting that "Save to map" is missing (The Armchair Parisian, September 16, 2014 at 3:16 pm). It is also stated that one should use the new Google Maps / Maps Engine to be able to "Save to Map".

[This page in Google help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3330854?rd=1), which refers to Google Maps Classic, confirms that by omission, since it only mentions "See your personal places in Maps", but nothing about adding.

**Is there any official confirmation that Classic Maps will not allow adding places anymore?**

**EDIT (4 years later)**: For a time, there was only one "Set" of "saved places" that one could use. After tons of user requests, now one can have several of "My Maps" storing Saved Places (bookmarks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a frequent My Maps user.

On 16 September, I received an email I had been expecting for some time (based on previous announcements from Google about Maps) saying

> Hi, We want to let you know that in the coming months, we're upgrading
>   the content you created in My Maps. All of the maps that you've
>   created will automatically move to the new Google My Maps (previously
>   called Google Maps Engine). Classic My Maps on maps.google.com will no
>   longer be available. You don't have to take any action to ensure all
>   your content will be upgraded.

The FAQ pointed to from this email says:   https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6009908

It doesn't explicitly say that the Save to Map feature has been removed - but then it's really about new Maps, not My Maps Classic.    Google's usual style would be to note announce feature removal like this, when the feature concerned is being replaced by another one.

Currently, if I go to maps.google.com, I am re-directed to the new maps.

However if I go to a website where one of my existing maps is embedded and click the "view in a larger map", I do go back to Classic My Maps, and am able to edit the existing map.   However when I am doing so, and I search for a place, there is no longer a Save to Map option.

I am expecting that the ability to edit maps in My Maps classic will be removed sooner or later - and at that point I personally will need to upgrade one account to My Maps Pro to get one of the features I need.